# Cannot read the Token when pass it to API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, token, jwt, access-token, postman

I am using JWT in order to authenticate the token. When I pass the request using postman API returns an error

> 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' cannot read this string: 'TokenValue!@%^&'

How to solve this

[image: Issue]

Postman request

[image: Postman Request]

```
http://localhost:52586/api/Doctor

Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer {{NurseAdminToken}}
```

Comment: the token you show in your second picture doesn't look like a JWT. What kind of token is it?

Answer (score 2):

Encode your token as Base64 string. and then send

so your Authorization header will be like:

Bearer e3tOdXJzZUFkbWluVG9rZW59fQ==

Refer this [jwt](http://www.jwt.io)

Comment: I am passing it as a Base64 Token. Please look at the screenshot. Is there anything wrong??

Comment: validate your formed token on www.jwt.io and if it is not valid there then you must have to check that token has formed accurately

Comment: People do not forget Bearer with B uppercase , we spend 30 min looking for the error and it was just 'B' upper

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass access token in http request as a header.Please look it in below

```
GET /api/api/Notification/GetNotifications HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.50:4551
Authorization: bearer 7fc4Z5ui--NVhvIBBwEWzJXGAROd7TBYprY-
8aQNuoSS7GSjhtikGksKss78GzT7CYPlGfPmnl-
TlTpCOQ9nYU1JTpAEwBGftqLHOSMUmX2BCIvk92S-DMForqb2l-
Cache-Control: no-cache
```